# Multi Label Classification : How to learn threshold values?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a deep CNN that works just fine for multi class classification. I would like to "upgrade" the challenge and train it on a multi label classification problem.

To do so I replaced my softmax by sigmoid and tried to train my network to minimize :

```
tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y_pred)
```

But I end up with weird prediction :

```
Prediction for Im1 : [ 0.59275776  0.08751075  0.37567005  0.1636796   0.42361438  0.08701646
```

0.38991812  0.54468459  0.34593087  0.82790571]

```
Prediction for Im1 : [ 0.52609032  0.07885984  0.45780018  0.04995904  0.32828355  0.07349177
```

0.35400775  0.36479294  0.30002621  0.84438241]

```
Prediction for Im1 : [ 0.58714485  0.03258472  0.3349618   0.03199361  0.54665488  0.02271551
```

0.43719986  0.54638696  0.20344526  0.88144571]

So I thought I try to make my network learn threshold for each class to determine if the sample belongs or not to te class.

So I added this to my code :

```
initial = tf.truncated_normal([numberOfClasses], stddev=0.1)
W_thresh = tf.Variable(initial)

y_predict_thresh = int(y_predict > W_thresh)
```

But I have an error :

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Tensor'.
```

Anybody has any idea to help me moving forward (How to avoid this error ?, Is the fact that my dataset is really unbalanced causes these kind of "constant" predictions ? Other suggestion for multi label classification ?, ...) ?

Thank you

EDIT: I just realized that doing thresholding might not be really cool for backpropagation :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know if you still need it, but you can use tensorflow transformation function `tf.to_int32, tf.to_int64`. Before evaluation your expression is an object to python, therefore it can't simply cast it to `int()`.

This does what you need:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    check = sess.run([tf.to_int64(W1 > W2)])
```

Comment: Thank you fro you ansewer. I actually realized the solution to my problem is not threshold but tackling the fact that I have an imbalanced dataset. But your answer is fine for my "threshold" question. Thank you again :)